# what is wrong in my program to add ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, imageview

I am using `main.xml` to add widgets to my activity, but for some reasons I want to add an `imageView` programmatically, this is my program,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.building_icon);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 100 ;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 100 ;
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this); // because I am working with frame layout
        fl.addView(imageView); 
        }
```

my `imageView` doesn't appear, please where I miss?

Comment: add the frame layout to your activity

Comment: @Raghunandan but I have one in main.xml ???

Comment: i dont see any findViewById() calls? how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @RiadSaadi the below answers should work if you have framelayout in `main.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a new `FrameLayout` and attached your `ImageView` to it but your `FrameLayout` is not attached to anything.

To reference the one in your `main.xml` do this:

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_frame_layout); 
fl.addView(imageView);
```

Where it's defined in your `main.xml` like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_frame_layout"
    ... />
```

Comment: my fram has no id !!                          <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating a content from xml with `setContentView`, then creating a new `ImageView` and adding it to a new `FrameLayout` that is not part of the original xml.

In order to add the `ImageView` to your `FrameLayout`, you need to first get a reference to the `FrameLayout` in your xml, using `findViewById` :

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
```

then you can add you `ImageView` to it using `addView` as you did :

```
container.addView(imageView);
```